# Magento sort collection with multiple attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

I want to sort Magento product collection  with multiple attributes at catalog product list page. I am using this code

```
$this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
$this->_collection->setOrder('price_plus_shipping', 'desc');
```

I also tried this code as well

```
$this->_collection->setOrder(array('price', 'price_plus_shipping'),Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
```

When i sort these both combine its not giving me accurate results but if i use both separately like when i am using only

> price_plus_shipping

its working fine also as

> price

its also working file 
they are showing me accurate results. But i want to use them combine.
in **Price** i have product prices in **price_plus_shipping** i have alphabets like

> a,b,c etc

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
$this->_collection->setOrder([$field1, $field2, ...], 'DESC');
```

OR Try this :

```
$this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order('price_plus_shipping desc');
```